# How to secure a WCF restful service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf-security

I used to deal with web services and we secured it using the credential header with soap. The calling application would need to pass a username and password in the credential header. We are now looking at using a WCF restful based webservice and want to secure it. Wondering what the best way to secure it is?

I was thinking that I could stuff a username and password in the POST variables (this thats what they are called). But is this the proper way to secure a restful web service?

Comment: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141484/how-to-configure-secure-restful-services-with-wcf-using-username-password-ssl) question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This link describes how to use [WCF with WS-Security](http://www.theserverside.net/tt/articles/showarticle.tss?id=SecuringWCFService).
This link describes what [WS-Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996951.aspx) is.
This link describes the [architecture of the WCF security component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788756.aspx).
Not sure if you can combine those with REST but know that HTTP has an authentication mechanisms of it's own (See [Basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) and [Digset authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) and this [overview about both](http://frontier.userland.com/stories/storyReader%242159)).
The RESTful way to do it imo would be using the HTTP authentication.
I think you have some research to be done :)

Comment: I did not find any information about securing a restfull wcf service in the mentioned links.

Comment: @BetaRide: Using those protocols you can. Just find the WCF docs. Right now I'd recommend using the Microsoft Web-API.