# Is REST web service secured for ASP.NET Web App

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, rest

Anyone please explain me. Is REST web service secured for ASP.NET Web Applications?

Comment: REST is as secure as HTTP.  Does that solve all security problems?

Comment: its not as secure as you can get with normal WCF.

Comment: The question is not clear much while REST web service and ASP.NET Web are two different thing?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by secured.

If the REST web service is hosted on an SSL secured domain then it would be secure in the sense that data involved would be encrypted.

Comment: "In that sense" - in what sense?  The sense that I suspect you mean is that you'd have some mmitigation against eavesdropping, but if the service doesn't authenticate/authorize its users then SSL has limited benefit.

Answer (score 0):

As written in above answer, it depends on your configuration. You can have a secure or partially secure REST service.

Check below links for clear understanding.

How to configure secure WCF rest services:

[How to configure secure RESTful services with WCF using username/password + SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141484/how-to-configure-secure-restful-services-with-wcf-using-username-password-ssl)

Securing WCF Rest services for ASP.NET:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1689271.aspx/1